# Error on ckan plugin-info after installing ckanext-dcat

Tags: dcat

I have successfully installed CKAN 2.8 on Ubuntu 16.04. I have successfully installed the basic charts extension as well. When I run the ckan plugin-info at that point I get a nicely formatted output with no errors (see below.)

However when I subsequently install ckanext-dcat using the same steps then ckan plugin-info yields the following:

```
root@localhost:/etc/ckan/default# ckan plugin-info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ckan", line 45, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PasteScript', 'console_scripts', 'paster')()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 102, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 141, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 236, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 1311, in command
    self.get_info()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 1316, in get_info
    self._load_config()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 330, in _load_config
    self.site_user = load_config(self.options.config, load_site_user)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 237, in load_config
    load_environment(conf.global_conf, conf.local_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/environment.py", line 116, in load_environment
    p.load_all()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 140, in load_all
    load(*plugins)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 154, in load
    service = _get_service(plugin)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 257, in _get_service
    raise PluginNotFoundException(plugin_name)
ckan.plugins.core.PluginNotFoundException: linechart
```

If I then reinstall the basic charts extension and execute ckan plugin-info then everything is back to normal (see below.)

Please assist with this issue as my primary objective is to input rdf datasets.

Thanks, Bill

ckan -plugin-info output (trucated to character limit) without ckanext-dcat:

root@localhost:/etc/ckan/default/ckanext-basiccharts# ckan plugin-info

### linechart:

Implements:
    IConfigurer
    IResourceView

### stats:

Stats plugin.
Implements:
    IConfigurer
    IRoutes

### image_view:

This plugin makes views of image resources, using an  tag
Implements:
    IConfigurer
    IResourceView

### recline_view:

```
This extension views resources using a Recline MultiView.
```

Implements:
    IConfigurer
    ITemplateHelpers
        get_dataproxy_url()

```
            Returns the value of the ckan.recline.dataproxy_url config option

    get_map_config()

            Extracts and returns map view configuration of the reclineview extension.

IResourceView
```

### text_view:

This extension previews JSON(P).
Implements:
    IConfigurer
    IConfigurable
    IResourceView

### domain_object_mods:

```
A domain object level interface to change notifications

Triggered by all edits to table and related tables, which we filter
out with check_real_change.
```

Implements:
    ISession

### barchart:

Implements:
    IConfigurer
    IResourceView

### piechart:

Implements:
    IConfigurer
    IResourceView

### basicgrid:

Implements:
    IConfigurer
    ITemplateHelpers
        view_data(resource_view)
    IResourceView

### synchronous_search:

Update the search index automatically.
Implements:
    IDomainObjectModification

### datastore:

Implements:
    IConfigurer
    IForkObserver
    IResourceController
    ITemplateHelpers
        datastore_dictionary(resource_id)

```
            Return the data dictionary info for a resource

IActions
    datastore_info(context, data_dict)

            Returns information about the data imported, such as column names
            and types.

            :rtype: A dictionary describing the columns and their types.
            :param id: Id of the resource we want info about
            :type id: A UUID

    datastore_function_create(context, data_dict)

            Create a trigger function for use with datastore_create

            :param name: function name
            :type name: string
            :param or_replace: True to replace if function already exists
                (default: False)
            :type or_replace: bool
            :param rettype: set to 'trigger'
                (only trigger functions may be created at this time)
            :type rettype: string
            :param definition: PL/pgSQL function body for trigger function
            :type definition: string

    datastore_create(context, data_dict)
        Adds a new table to the DataStore.

            The datastore_create action allows you to post JSON data to be
            stored against a resource. This endpoint also supports altering tables,
            aliases and indexes and bulk insertion. This endpoint can be called
            multiple times to initially insert more data, add fields, change the
            aliases or indexes as well as the primary keys.

            To create an empty datastore resource and a CKAN resource at the same time,
            provide ``resource`` with a valid ``package_id`` and omit the
            ``resource_id``.

            If you want to create a datastore resource from the content of a file,
            provide ``resource`` with a valid ``url``.

            See :ref:`fields` and :ref:`records` for details on how to lay out records.

            :param resource_id: resource id that the data is going to be stored
                                against.
            :type resource_id: string
            :param force: set to True to edit a read-only resource
            :type force: bool (optional, default: False)
            :param resource: resource dictionary that is passed to
                :meth:`~ckan.logic.action.create.resource_create`.
                Use instead of ``resource_id`` (optional)
            :type resource: dictionary
            :param aliases: names for read only aliases of the resource. (optional)
            :type aliases: list or comma separated string
            :param fields: fields/columns and their extra metadata. (optional)
            :type fields: list of dictionaries
            :param records: the data, eg: [{"dob": "2005", "some_stuff": ["a", "b"]}]
                            (optional)
            :type records: list of dictionaries
            :param primary_key: fields that represent a unique key (optional)
            :type primary_key: list or comma separated string
            :param indexes: indexes on table (optional)
            :type indexes: list or comma separated string
            :param triggers: trigger functions to apply to this table on update/insert.
                functions may be created with
                :meth:`~ckanext.datastore.logic.action.datastore_function_create`.
                eg: [
                {"function": "trigger_clean_reference"},
                {"function": "trigger_check_codes"}]
            :type triggers: list of dictionaries

            Please note that setting the ``aliases``, ``indexes`` or ``primary_key``
            replaces the exising aliases or constraints. Setting ``records`` appends
            the provided records to the resource.

            **Results:**

            :returns: The newly created data object, excluding ``records`` passed.
            :rtype: dictionary

            See :ref:`fields` and :ref:`records` for details on how to lay out records.


    datastore_function_delete(context, data_dict)

            Delete a trigger function

            :param name: function name
            :type name: string

    datastore_upsert(context, data_dict)
        Updates or inserts into a table in the DataStore

            The datastore_upsert API action allows you to add or edit records to
            an existing DataStore resource. In order for the *upsert* and *update*
            methods to work, a unique key has to be defined via the datastore_create
            action. The available methods are:

            *upsert*
                Update if record with same key already exists, otherwise insert.
                Requires unique key.
            *insert*
                Insert only. This method is faster that upsert, but will fail if any
                inserted record matches an existing one. Does *not* require a unique
                key.
            *update*
                Update only. An exception will occur if the key that should be updated
                does not exist. Requires unique key.


            :param resource_id: resource id that the data is going to be stored under.
            :type resource_id: string
            :param force: set to True to edit a read-only resource
            :type force: bool (optional, default: False)
            :param records: the data, eg: [{"dob": "2005", "some_stuff": ["a","b"]}]
                            (optional)
            :type records: list of dictionaries
            :param method: the method to use to put the data into the datastore.
                           Possible options are: upsert, insert, update
                           (optional, default: upsert)
            :type method: string

            **Results:**

            :returns: The modified data object.
            :rtype: dictionary


    datastore_search_sql(context, data_dict)
        Execute SQL queries on the DataStore.

            The datastore_search_sql action allows a user to search data in a resource
            or connect multiple resources with join expressions. The underlying SQL
            engine is the
            `PostgreSQL engine <http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/>`_.
            There is an enforced timeout on SQL queries to avoid an unintended DOS.
            Queries are only allowed if you have access to the all the CKAN resources
            in the query and send the appropriate authorization.

            .. note:: This action is not available when
                :ref:`ckan.datastore.sqlsearch.enabled` is set to false

            .. note:: When source data columns (i.e. CSV) heading names are provdied
                in all UPPERCASE you need to double quote them in the SQL select
                statement to avoid returning null results.

            :param sql: a single SQL select statement
            :type sql: string

            **Results:**

            The result of this action is a dictionary with the following keys:

            :rtype: A dictionary with the following keys
            :param fields: fields/columns and their extra metadata
            :type fields: list of dictionaries
            :param records: list of matching results
            :type records: list of dictionaries


    datastore_run_triggers(context, data_dict)
         update each record with trigger

            The datastore_run_triggers API action allows you to re-apply exisitng
            triggers to an existing DataStore resource.

            :param resource_id: resource id that the data is going to be stored under.
            :type resource_id: string

            **Results:**

            :returns: The rowcount in the table.
            :rtype: int


    datastore_search(context, data_dict)
        Search a DataStore resource.

            The datastore_search action allows you to search data in a resource.
            DataStore resources that belong to private CKAN resource can only be
            read by you if you have access to the CKAN resource and send the
            appropriate authorization.

            :param resource_id: id or alias of the resource to be searched against
            :type resource_id: string
            :param filters: matching conditions to select, e.g
                            {"key1": "a", "key2": "b"} (optional)
            :type filters: dictionary
            :param q: full text query. If it's a string, it'll search on all fields on
                      each row. If it's a dictionary as {"key1": "a", "key2": "b"},
                      it'll search on each specific field (optional)
            :type q: string or dictionary
            :param distinct: return only distinct rows (optional, default: false)
            :type distinct: bool
            :param plain: treat as plain text query (optional, default: true)
            :type plain: bool
            :param language: language of the full text query
                             (optional, default: english)
            :type language: string
            :param limit: maximum number of rows to return (optional, default: 100)
            :type limit: int
            :param offset: offset this number of rows (optional)
            :type offset: int
            :param fields: fields to return
                           (optional, default: all fields in original order)
            :type fields: list or comma separated string
            :param sort: comma separated field names with ordering
                         e.g.: "fieldname1, fieldname2 desc"
            :type sort: string
            :param include_total: True to return total matching record count
                                  (optional, default: true)
            :type include_total: bool
            :param records_format: the format for the records return value:
                'objects' (default) list of {fieldname1: value1, ...} dicts,
                'lists' list of [value1, value2, ...] lists,
                'csv' string containing comma-separated values with no header,
                'tsv' string containing tab-separated values with no header
            :type records_format: controlled list


            Setting the ``plain`` flag to false enables the entire PostgreSQL
            `full text search query language`_.

            A listing of all available resources can be found at the
            alias ``_table_metadata``.

            .. _full text search query language: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-textsearch.html#DATATYPE-TSQUERY

            If you need to download the full resource, read :ref:`dump`.

            **Results:**

            The result of this action is a dictionary with the following keys:

            :rtype: A dictionary with the following keys
            :param fields: fields/columns and their extra metadata
            :type fields: list of dictionaries
            :param offset: query offset value
            :type offset: int
            :param limit: query limit value
            :type limit: int
            :param filters: query filters
            :type filters: list of dictionaries
            :param total: number of total matching records
            :type total: int
            :param records: list of matching results
            :type records: depends on records_format value passed


    datastore_delete(context, data_dict)
        Deletes a table or a set of records from the DataStore.

            :param resource_id: resource id that the data will be deleted from.
                                (optional)
            :type resource_id: string
            :param force: set to True to edit a read-only resource
            :type force: bool (optional, default: False)
            :param filters: filters to apply before deleting (eg {"name": "fred"}).
                           If missing delete whole table and all dependent views.
                           (optional)
            :type filters: dictionary

            **Results:**

            :returns: Original filters sent.
            :rtype: dictionary


IConfigurable
IRoutes
IAuthFunctions
```

root@localhost:/etc/ckan/default/ckanext-basiccharts# lsb_release -aNo LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
root@localhost:/etc/ckan/default/ckanext-basiccharts# ckan plugin-info

### linechart:

Implements:
    IConfigurer
    IResourceView

### stats:

Stats plugin.
Implements:
    IConfigurer
    IRoutes

### image_view:

This plugin makes views of image resources, using an  tag
Implements:
    IConfigurer
    IResourceView

### recline_view:

```
This extension views resources using a Recline MultiView.
```

Implements:
    IConfigurer
    ITemplateHelpers
        get_dataproxy_url()

```
            Returns the value of the ckan.recline.dataproxy_url config option

    get_map_config()

            Extracts and returns map view configuration of the reclineview extension.

IResourceView
```

### text_view:

This extension previews JSON(P).
Implements:
    IConfigurer
    IConfigurable
    IResourceView

### domain_object_mods:

```
A domain object level interface to change notifications

Triggered by all edits to table and related tables, which we filter
out with check_real_change.
```

Implements:
    ISession

### barchart:

Implements:
    IConfigurer
    IResourceView

### piechart:

Implements:
    IConfigurer
    IResourceView

### basicgrid:

Implements:
    IConfigurer
    ITemplateHelpers
        view_data(resource_view)
    IResourceView

### synchronous_search:

Update the search index automatically.
Implements:
    IDomainObjectModification